# Possible to display different messages on separate lines for an AlertDialog?

Tags: android

I want to set up my AlertDialog so that I can display different information on different lines at different times. So the first line might have a general message like "Login failed," and then the second line would divulge extra information regarding that first line, like "Failed to connect to server."

I need to be able to set those messages at my choosing (through the program's instructions).

I am not asking for how to program this... but rather, is this possible? To me it seems like AlertDialog only knows about one line of text and that's controlled through setMessage.

Even if I built a layout with two TextViews', I still have no way to access that second text view. Any guidance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `setTitle`? Also you can `setMessage` like this `.setmessage("What you want your title to be\n\n Your message")` That way it will look like a title, but I'm sure that `.setTitle will work`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is actually possible to do what I wanted, but Rotary Heart's solution works just as well. Thank you.